# How to plot values from multiple columns as discrete variables on the x axis using ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, graph

I have a dataframe which is structured like this

```
data <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 2, 3), Value1=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.8), Value2=c(0.6, 0.3, 0.8), Value3=c(0.6, 0.6, 0.6))
```

I want to plot it so I have Value1, Value2 and Value3 as discrete variables on the X axis. Then on  the Y axis the respective value corresponding to them.

Then I want to plot the values corresponding to each ID.

I can do this by

```
ggplot(data) + geom_point(aes('Value1', Value1), colour=factor(data$ID)) + geom_point(aes('Value2', Value2), colour=factor(data$ID)) + geom_point(aes('Value3', Value3), colour=factor(data$ID))
```

However what I would like to do now is to connect a line between the 3 points of each ID. I have tried using geom_line(), but I can't figure out how to get it to view these data as a series. It seems pretty trivial but I cant work out how to get the mappings right to do this.

Can anyone help with that? And if anyone can think of a more efficient way to do the first part then I'd be keen to hear that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by pivoting your data.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(ID = factor(ID)) # so it is not treated as a continuous variable
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Value"), names_to = "Variable") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Variable, y = value, group = ID, color = ID)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I want. However, when I run the code I get this error 'Error: `starts_with()` must be used within a *selecting* function.' How do I resolve?

Comment: `starts_with()` is imported from the `tidyselect` package into `tidyr` (which is where `pivot_longer()` is from. Using `packageVersion()`, here are the versions of the packages: `tidyselect` is 1.1.0 and `tidyr` is 1.1.2. If you are using an older version of these packages, the functionality for `pivot_longer()` might not be fully implemented.

Comment: I have tidyselect 1.1.0 and tidyr 1.1.3.

Comment: I fixed it. Had to insert the dataframe at the first position, so starts_with("Value") could be interpreted as the cols argument in second position.

pivot_longer(*data*, starts_with("Value"), names_to = "Variable")

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you need pivot_longer

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 2, 3), Value1=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.8), Value2=c(0.6, 0.3, 0.8), Value3=c(0.6, 0.6, 0.6))

data_longer = data %>% 
  pivot_longer(!ID, names_to = "type", values_to = "count") 

ggplot(data_longer, aes(x=ID, y=count, colour = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```